# SQL Server Adapter for Rails

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby

Trying to find the sqlserver adapter for rails on windows.

I have tried getting it from (without luck):

gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter --source=http://gems.rubyonrails.org

Where else can I get this gem?

***UPDATE:***

Make sure to run the command prompt as the administrator. Right click on the command prompt and click "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran the exact command line you did, and the gem installs fine.

Questions:

1. Are you running Vista?

   - If so, make sure you run your command prompt with administrative access, so it can write to the gems folder
2. Do you have the latest version of gems?

   - Run `gem --version` to find out what you have, if it's not 1.2.0, then run `gem update --system` to get the latest